# Php Syntax error. Unsure where

Tags: php

```
beginning of php
<?php
echo "Began";
$Title=$_GET["Title"];
$Des=$_GET["description"];
$Url=$_GET["url"];
$Date=$_GET["time"];
echo "4 lines";
$Loc=$_GET["location"];
$Num=$_GET["num"];
$info01=array($Title,$Des,$Url,$Date);
$info02=array("<title>","<description>","<date>","<url>");
$info03=array("</title>","</description>","</date>","</url>");

     $File = .$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml"; 
     $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');

     $Data = "<rss>\n"; 
     fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
        for ($i=0; $i <= 3; $i++){
            echo $i;
             $Data = $info02[$i].$info01[$i].$info03[$i]."\n"; 
             fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
        }

  $Data = "</rss>\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 echo "Data Written"; 
 fclose($Handle); 

?>

<form action="check.php" method="get">
Title <input type="text" name="Title"><br>
Description <input type="text" name="description"><br>
URL <input type="text" name="url"><br>
DATE <input type="text" name="time"><br>
Rss location <input type="text" name="location"><br>
Rss Number <input type="text" name="num">
 <input type="submit">
```

Can any one help me with this?

I am getting an error, some where whether syntax or not, I do not know.

I looked at the code for some time an haven’t seen why there are errors.

I think it could be syntax. thats as far as I got.

thank you in advances

Comment: what is the error show to you?

Comment: `$File = .$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";` error may be with this line remove that `.` infront of `$Loc`

Comment: error itself give us the information as where and what is the error. Just take time to read the error.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't belive that little thing. screwed everything else up.

Answer (score 2):

Try using , You have added `.` infront of `$Loc` variable

```
 $File = $Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```

instead of

```
$File = .$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "." (dot) before your variable ($Loc)

```
$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$File = .$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";` error may be with this line remove that `.` infront of `$Loc`

Answer (score 0):

Remove first . from this

```
$File = .$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```

to

```
$File = $Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the line

```
$File = .$Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```

I did not cross-check, but I think the dot right before $Loc should not be there.
Try this:

```
$File = $Loc."rss".$Num.".xml";
```